# Which of following option(s) are correct for a symmetric real matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A = [[a_{ij}]]$ be an $n \times n$- non-singular symmetric matrix such that each $a_{ij}$ is a
positive integer. Then we can conclude that

(A) the determinant of $A$ is a positive integer

(B) the trace of $A$ is a positive integer.

(C) the matrix $A^{-1}$ has positive entries.

(D) the matrix $A^2$ has positive entries.

I took matrix $$ \left(\begin{array}{cc} 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 4 \end{array}\right)$$

So i have left with B and D as correct ? I am not sure though

Comment: B and D are the correct answers, so you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an example matrix to disprove some of the points, but if you suspect a point is true then you can only be sure if you prove it for all matrices with the properties mentioned.

So A you have disproved with your example.

B: surely if every entry of the matrix is positive, then so is every entry on the diagonal, and if you sum these positive entries on the diagonal, you will have a positive number as result. So B is true.

C: Your example is a counter-example.

D: Every entry of $A^2$ is the sum of products of positive numbers, and hence will also be positive. So you can be sure that this one is true as well.